# Does groovy automatically generate no-args constructor?

Tags: groovy, constructor

In java, **no-args constructor** is generated when you didn't explicitly specify a constructor, and by the time you write your constructor (with arguments), you need now to explicitly specify that **no-args constructor**.

How about in groovy, do you also need to explicitly specify this **no-args constructor** when writing your own constructor ( with arguments ) or gvm implicitly generates this?

Comment: google for "groovy constructors", and click on the first result. Or just go to the groovy documentation, click "Constructors" in the table of contents, and read: http://www.groovy-lang.org/objectorientation.html#_constructors

Comment: Or type a class into the groovy console, and open the ast inspector

Comment: gvm has nothing to do with how groovy treats its classes.

Answer (score 2):

> How about in groovy, do you also need to explicitly specify this
>   no-args constructor when writing your own constructor ( with arguments
>   ) or gvm implicitly generates this?

GVM doesn't have anything to do with any of this.

If you define any constructors that accept arguments then a no-arg constructor will not generated.  If you want it, you need to define it.

```
$ cat Demo.groovy 

public class Demo {
    public Demo(String s) {}
}

$ groovyc Demo.groovy 

$ javap Demo

Compiled from "Demo.groovy"
public class Demo implements groovy.lang.GroovyObject {
  public static transient boolean __$stMC;
  public Demo(java.lang.String);
  protected groovy.lang.MetaClass $getStaticMetaClass();
  public groovy.lang.MetaClass getMetaClass();
  public void setMetaClass(groovy.lang.MetaClass);
  public java.lang.Object invokeMethod(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object);
  public java.lang.Object getProperty(java.lang.String);
  public void setProperty(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object);
}
```